# Incorrect display of 4 byte emojis in vs code integrated terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, utf-8, cygwin, git-bash, mintty

Why is my VSCode integrated terminal not able to show correct emojis:

Text file:

```
 Emoji
```

which produces with `cat file.txt` the output:

```
� Emoji
```

I use a proper UTF8 font `MesloLGS NF` (pk10 powerline font).
I use `git-bash.exe`. Starting git-bash.exe from the task bar (mintty terminal?) works fine with these emojis. Also 3 bytes emojis work.

Any clue very welcome.

Comment: What's the difference for `locale -a` in mintty and vscode ?

Comment: What's output from `hexdump -C -n 10  file.txt`? Maybe there is a BOM?

Comment: What shell are you using in your VS Code integrated terminal? The default is PowerShell, but you can change it to Git Bash by following the directions at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_windows. Often UTF-8 issues are solved by switching from PowerShell (or CMD) to Git Bash. Also try putting `export TERM=xterm` in your ~/.bash_profile. I've written a bit about this at https://www.ii.com/git-bash-is-my-preferred-windows-shell/

Comment: I have this issue too and I'm really curious about this. Here's a possible clue: If you run `chcp.com` in VS Code terminal running Git Bash, it displays `Active code page: 437`. In mintty, `chcp.com` displays `Active code page: 65001`. In VS Code's terminal I ran `chcp.com 65001` but still get the box question mark character. There's some kind of weird emoji sequence/code page/encoding/UTF-8/UTF-16 thing going on here and I'm wondering if this should be posted in the VS Code GitHub Issues?

Answer (score 0):

Changing codepage to `chcp.com 65001` and using the newest VS Code
`cat A.txt` with content  `Emoji`
works.